# Почему выводит None вместо числа?

Tags: python, sqlite3, aiogram-3.x

Есть телеграмм бот на aiogram, подключил туда бд и добавил строку ballance где хранится число, при выводе ballance выводит None

```
class Get в бд:
    
    def get_ballance(user_id):
        cur.execute('SELECT 2 FROM users WHERE user_id == "{}"'.format(user_id)).fetchone()
```

Обработчик команды ballance:

```
@router.message(Command('ballance'))
async def ballance_msg(message: Message):
    ballance = Get.get_ballance(user_id=message.from_user.id)
    await message.answer(f'Ваш баланс: {ballance}')
```

UPD чутка изменил код
Class Get в бд:

```
int = cur.execute('SELECT 2 FROM users WHERE user_id == "{}"'.format(user_id)).fetchone()
return (int)
```

Теперь вывод:

```
  Ваш баланс: (0,)
```

как убрать скобки и запятую?

Comment: проблема в том, что в базе есть такая строчка, но почему то код ее не видит, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Нельзя использовать `.format` для подстановки параметров в запрос.

Comment: `get_ballance` ничего не возвращает. Сделайте `return` со значением, которое вы хотите вернуть.

Comment: cделал все как вы сказали, в бд прописал: return ballance, теперь бот выводит сообщение Ваш баланс: (0,) не подскажите как убрать скобки и запятую?

Comment: Взять первый элемент из этого кортежа

Comment: Спасибо! Благодаря вашим комментариям все получилось!

Answer (score 1):

Измени метод запроса баланса во-первых на запрос с подстановкой данный через параметры, форматирование запроса плохой выбор ввиду подверженности атаке `SQL Injection`. Во-вторых `fetchone` дает кортеж, поэтому неоходимо обратиться по индексу `0` чтобы достать значение

```
def get_balance(user_id):
    return cur.execute('SELECT 2 FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id;', {"user_id": user_id}).fetchone()[0]
```